# MySQL. Procedure, wrong syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to learn how procedures work and I get an error and I don't know why.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE producer
(IN marcaMasinii VARCHAR(20))
SELECT DISTINCT producator, AVG(pret) AS medie 
FROM vehicul v
JOIN proprietate p
ON v.id_vehicul = p.nr_vehicul
WHERE producator = marcaMasinii;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL producer("Dacia");
```

I have this procedure and I get an error on the line where "END //" is. 
The error sounds like this:

```
"Syntax error, unexpected END, expecting $END."
```

If I add the "BEGIN", the code looks like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE producer
(IN marcaMasinii VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT producator, AVG(pret) AS medie 
FROM vehicul v
JOIN proprietate p
ON v.id_vehicul = p.nr_vehicul
WHERE producator = marcaMasinii;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL producer("Dacia");
```

The error looks like this:

```
"Syntax error, unexpected CREATE, expecting END_OF_INPUT or ;"
```

What's wrong with the syntax? Can someone explain?

Comment: You are missing BEGIN hence END is unexpected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `BEGIN` before `SELECT`. You need to read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html first.